# Google Map API: Open the url by clicking on marker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string markers = BindMarker();
    Literal1.Text = @"
       <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function () {
        LoadMap();
        }

       function LoadMap() {

        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937,78.9629),
        zoom: 4,
        };

       var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);" + markers + @"

       var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});


       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.open(myMap, marker);
       });

      }
      </script>";

}

public string BindMarker()
{
    con.Open();
    string markers = "";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Univ_Name, Latitude, Longitude, Univ_Website FROM Location", con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        i++;
        markers += @"var marker, contentString" + i.ToString() + @" = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + reader["Latitude"].ToString() + ", " +
          reader["Longitude"].ToString() + ")," + @"map: myMap, title:'" + reader["Univ_Name"].ToString() + "'}, {contentString: new google.maps.InfoWindow('" + reader["Univ_Website"].ToString() + "')});\n";
        //Response.Write(markers);
    }

    return markers;
}}
```

I've got google maps in my application. Everything is working as it should, except for one problem. I've checked the code and the InfoWindow is still not showing. When I inspected the map in chrome and it showed "Uncaught ReferenceError: contentString is not defined" error in console.

I can't seem to find where I went wrong with this. Please help with the problem